# Does Snowflake DB support subqueries in FROM clause?

Tags: sql, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have looked at their documentation and they do support subqueries but it is not clear if I can have a subquery in the FROM clause.

If so, can you please show me the proper syntax?

My query:

---

```
select C1 C1, 2 C2, 3 C3 
from 
( 
select X.*, *, Y.*, Y.SNO C1 
from Y, X 
) T1
```

---

Comment: Sample data and expected results, please. Your query is proper syntax

Comment: It says [in their documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/operators-subquery.html) that it is allowed. `SELECT t1.f1 FROM (SELECT f1 FROM some_table) as t1` would be the proper syntax. Not sure what you are trying to do with your `C1 C1` or `2 C2` columns... (it's nonsense) so can't help out any further than that.

Comment: What happened when you ran that statement?

Comment: Ive never heard of snowflake DB but would imagine that it will complain about duplicate column names in the derived table from `select X.*, *, Y.*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It definitely does! Example below. If your query doesn't work, please provide a full repro case and an error message.

```
create or replace table x(i int) as 
select column1 from values(1),(1),(2),(3),(2);

select * from x, (select avg(i) from x);
---+--------+
 I | AVG(I) |
---+--------+
 1 | 1.800  |
 1 | 1.800  |
 2 | 1.800  |
 3 | 1.800  |
 2 | 1.800  |
---+--------+

select count(*) from (select distinct i from x);
----------+
 COUNT(*) |
----------+
 3        |
----------+
```